# Simplest way to do an array literal in MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I would like to get the array `[1,2,3]` in mysql. For example:

```
with tbl (id) as (
    select 1 union select 2 union select 3
) select 'something', json_arrayagg(id) from tbl

# something, json_arrayagg(id)
# 'something', '[1, 2, 3]'
```

Would there be a simpler way to do this rather than sort of 'building up a table' in a CTE and then grouping it outside it?

---

For example, I am trying to do something like this (if possible):

```
SELECT '1', [1,2,3]
```

> `MySQL '8.0.20'` Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[1,2,3]) ids from sort group by letter order by ids asc  SELECT '1', [1,2,3]' at line 4

Comment: Can you give us some context here?  I mean, what is wrong with the literal `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it doesn't work (for me) in mysql8. Are you able to do this yourself?

Comment: [Working for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1258c354e67bbe023cdacef23b009039) ...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh I see -- yes it's working for me too! I mean without using the `cte` and just using `[1,2,3]` or something simpler.

Comment: Well, `[1, 2, 3]` is in fact a valid JSON literal as far as I know.  I'm not sure what you have in mind here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen right, but you 'constructed' it by doing `json_arrayagg(column)`, right? I'm asking if there's a more straightforward way to construct it without having to reference a column.

Comment: Please give us some context here.  If you _can't_ form a JSON literal `[1, 2, 3]`, then tell us why you can't do that and why your current approach might be better?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen are you sure what you linked me is the correct one then? When I click it it's just the same as my question: https://imgur.com/a/pCX5h7m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much commenting above, your actual question has come out, which is that you are confused about how to work with JSON literals in MySQL.  Valid JSON literals in MySQL always are surrounded by single quotes, just like string literals.  Consider this small example:

```sql
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '1' AS id, '[1,2,3]' AS array
)

SELECT Id, JSON_EXTRACT(array, '$[2]') AS third
FROM yourTable;
```

This outputs `1, 3` as the [demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e616e88c64a6ef18a8af2d1af914699c) shows.  The key here is that the JSON array literal, which you already know how to form, is in single quotes.

Comment: ah got it, the 'json' part should be self-explanatory: it's not a native array -- thank you!

Comment: @David542 Basically _all_ SQL databases have terse and confusing JSON APIs...sometimes it is a real headache.